# Groups of U(n) and how they are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, group-isomorphism

I have to show that U(140) is isomorphic to U(144). I understand that $U(140)=U(2^2)+U(5)+U(7)$ and $U(144)=U(2^4)+U(3^2)$. How can I use this fact and the fact to show that its isomorphic?

I have completed this step, but now I am stuck on the part below.

Also, Show that U(pq) is never cyclic for p and q are distinct odd primes. Any tips?

Comment: Your first paragraph can't be right because $144 \neq 140$. That's actually a hint. Can you state the exact definition of $U$? There's something wrong with your usage.

Comment: @user4894: I expect that the OP means
$$U(n)=(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$$

Comment: @curious I know what the OP means, I'm trying to make sure *the OP* understands what the OP means. Giving a hint rather than the solution was what I had in mind, anyway. The equalities the OP wrote are incorrect and I want the OP to figure out why.

Comment: it is what curious says it is, all the integers relatively prime to it.

Comment: @Jack Oh you're the OP. Then can you see that the equalities you wrote are incorrect? The factors of the one multiply to 140, and the factors of the other multiply to 144. So they can't possibly be isomorphic. Therefore something is wrong with your equalities for U(n).

Comment: OP? what does that mean

Comment: Original Poster. You, in this case.

Comment: Okay, I mean thats what I was given, so then there is an error in that sense.

Comment: Try using the Euler phi function. I think I misinterpreted your notation so my remarks might be a bit off. By '+' do you mean direct sum? If so, then the numbers in your equality don't come out. Hint: Note that phi(144) = 48 = phi(140). That's the point of my comments.

Comment: I mean the plus with the circle around it, I dont know the notation for it

Comment: Sorry my comments were a little confusing. Main point is that phi(140) = phi(144).